# How to have symlink to content of source up to date?

Tags: symlink

So, by doing `ln -s /my/source/* ./`

I created a link to content of source but changes in source aren't reflected in the target.

For example, when I create new folder in source it's not being shown in target

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the expected behavior. Your command will make links for current contents of /my/source/ directory.

The easy solution is to link the directory itself:

```
ln -s /my/source ./
```

it will create a link like:

```
source -> /my/source
```

But also [inotifytools](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/) can be used to watch the directory and take an action.

Comment: Creating link to directory wouldn't work since I want to have content from multiple locations.It wasn't mentioned in the question but it would be the final goal.